# How to add 6 months to a given date in SQL

Tags: sql, date, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to create a new date column by taking a date from previous column and then adding 6 months to it.

My data fields looks like this,
[image]

I want to create another column to it by taking index date then adding 6months to that date for each patients in my data.
I tried using the following query but it's giving me an error.

```
select PATIENT_ID, INDEX_DATE, DATE_ADD(INDEX_DATE, INTERVAL + 6 MONTH) as Ref_Index
FROM table;
```

Ref_Index is the new column I'm trying to create.

Is there any other way to apply the mentioned logic?

Answer (score 1):

In Snowflake you can also use [ADD_MONTHS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/add_months.html) function to achieve the same:

```
select add_months(INDEX_DATE, 6) as ref_index from table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the `+` from the `DATE_ADD` function.

```
select PATIENT_ID, INDEX_DATE, DATE_ADD(INDEX_DATE, INTERVAL 6 MONTH) as Ref_Index
FROM table;
```

In the change you're using T-SQL, the function parameters are slightly different.

```
select PATIENT_ID, INDEX_DATE, DATE_ADD(month, 6, INDEX_DATE) as Ref_Index
FROM table;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the interval:

```
SELECT
  patient_id,
  index_date, 
  index_date + INTERVAL '6 MONTHS' AS ref_index
FROM table;
```

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-datetime.html#interval-constants

Answer (score 0):

In Snowflake, it's called `dateadd` not `date_add`. So change to `dateadd(month, 6, index_date)`